# I have two colums in Excel but I want to import certain sections to C# program

Tags: c#, excel, combobox, oledb

My Excel is :

```
region            city
iç anadolu        ankara
iç anadolu        ankara
iç anadolu        ankara
iç anadolu        ankara
iç anadolu        kayseri
marmara           istanbul
marmara           istanbul
marmara           istanbul
marmara           bursa
marmara           bursa
```

I want to that when `iç anadolu` is selected in combobox1, only `ankara` and `kayseri` are appeared in combobox2 and, when `marmara` is selected in combobox1, only `istanbul` and `bursa` are appeared in combobox2.

How can I do that?

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;
namespace trfd
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
 }
   OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\users\\toshiba\\desktop\\proje_ofy\\proje-1; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");    
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        baglan.Open();
        string sql = "SELECT  * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A100]";
        OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand(sql, baglan);
        OleDbDataReader dr = null;
        dr = komut.ExecuteReader();                   
        while (dr.Read()) {
            if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(dr[0].ToString()))
                { 
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());                 
           }
```

}

```
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
    }
    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
    }
```

}
}

Comment: The code you've provided has nothing to do with your question (other than populating the combo boxes on load), what have you tried?.

Comment: button1 is unnecessary. I know that we write something in combobox1_selectedındexcanged. but I have no idea what I write to do my request. So they are empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow below code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\d.faldu\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\tempExcel; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");

    baglan.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A100]";
    OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand(sql, baglan);
    OleDbDataReader dr = null;
    dr = komut.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains(dr[0].ToString()))
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
        }
    }
    baglan.Close();   
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox2.Items.Clear();

    OleDbConnection baglan = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\d.faldu\Desktop\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\tempExcel; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
    baglan.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$B1:B100]";
    OleDbCommand komut = new OleDbCommand(sql, baglan);
    OleDbDataReader dr = null;
    dr = komut.ExecuteReader();

    string sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:A100]";
    OleDbCommand komut_2 = new OleDbCommand(sql_2, baglan);
    OleDbDataReader dr_2 = null;
    dr_2 = komut_2.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr_2.Read() && dr.Read())
    {
        if (dr_2[0].ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            if (!comboBox2.Items.Contains(dr[0].ToString()))
            {
                comboBox2.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    baglan.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's great for me :D

Comment: if my answer helpful than please go for vote up ! :)